# Assign textview value from a hashmap string

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-activity, hashmap

i have a problem here with my program, i am trying to set a dynamic value for my Text View name the that will be assign to it will be coming from a map (see below).. It seems fine when i try to print the value on the log cat but when i am got to put it on the text view itself it becomes null.. thanks

```
protected void setMap(HashMap<String, String> map) {

    String value=map.get("key");
    //printing on logcat works fine
    System.out.println(value);
    //name is a TextView, I initialized it on Oncreate()
    name.setText(value);
    //the setText causes NullPointerException

}
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587909/why-my-data-results-to-nullpointerexception-when-use-it-on-ui-but-works-fine-on

Comment: not the value, but the text-field reference (e.g. `name`) *is* `null`

Comment: Where did you define `name`?

Comment: name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

Comment: im helping my friend out here. hays

Comment: as @Lukas Knuth said, not your value is null, but your TextView name is null.    
please post your layout XML here for us to locate the problem

Comment: <TextView
 android:id="@+id/name"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Name"
 android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
 android:textColor="#fff" />

@Lukas Knuth: i pretty sure that the text field is not null if thats what you mean. by the way of the map is from a JSON response.

Comment: Post a StackTrace and more code.

Comment: @GreenFox why not make your friend ask the question instead of you asking the qeustion? he/she might unserstand more the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less a short in the dark as you've provided very little information.

But try the following in `onCreateView()` of the fragment which has the `setMap` method:

```
 name = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name);
```